# Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

Tags: android, android-studio, lambda, java-8, android-studio-2.3

As per mentioned in developer.android website

> "The Jack toolchain is deprecated, as per this announcement. If your
>   project depends on Jack, you should migrate to using Java 8 support
>   built into Android Studio’s default toolchain."

[image]

I need to use lambda expressions so I have disabled the jack options, but when I compile my code, I get the following error

```
Error:Jack is required to support Java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
```

Below is the screenshot of my build.gradle file

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check you version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle`.

I had the same error. My solution:

- set `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6`
- update kotlin to `1.1.3-2`
- add to repositories `google()`

I'm using AS 3.0 Canary 6.

Comment: what if we don't use the beta version of AS, no workaround on this?

Answer (score 4):

You should do the following:

- Update your **Android Studio** to version **3.0.1**.
- Upgrade your **gradle** to **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'**
- Make sure you **buildToolsVersion** is at least **26.0.2**.

After that you can remove Jack options and use supported Java 8 features.